# Is placeholder supports IE 8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, haml, onedrive

I think IE 8 doesn't support placeholder, but when i load www.skydrive.com it comes with placeholder text as "someone@example.com & password"

Is there any way to access placeholder without jQuery etc in IE 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder) the `placeholder` attribute came in IE10.

[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) is a good library for doing feature detection such as this and they also have a [great list of polyfils you can use](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms--input-placeholder).

Comment: how do i set jQuery path from my desktop in haml ?

Comment: I'd suggest you start another question which you can detail the problem with HAML

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your header. Hope it helps

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```